# Trying to display "degree f" symbol on a SERLCD

Tags: unicode, micropython, lcd, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to display a "degree f" symbol on a SERLCD LCD display from a Raspberry Pi Pico using MicroPython:

```py
import machine
import utime

sda = machine.Pin(0)
scl = machine.Pin(1)
i2c = machine.I2C(0, sda = sda, scl = scl, freq = 400000)
print(i2c.scan())  #Prints 114
utime.sleep_ms(100)
i2c.writeto(114, '\x7C')   #Sending hexadecimal string
i2c.writeto(114, '\x2D')   #2D blanks the display and sets the cursor to the beginning
y = str(1234)    #Test character  
#i2c.writeto(114,  str(10.5) + str(u'\xb0'))   #Works OK
i2c.writeto(114, "Count:" + y + (str('u\2109')))
```

The display is Count 1234132. u\2109 is Unicode for the degree Fahrenheit symbol. What is the proper way to display the symbol?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, to display a special character you will have to send a hexadecimal string which is converted by the display driver according to its charset.

The whole documentation for your display driver is available [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf). But, if you just want to look into the charset, you can find it on [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD44780#/media/Datei:Charset.gif) as well.

In the charset, the character you're looking for is located in the bottom right corner. It's binary identifier – which you can identify by looking at the table head and the beginning of its corresponding row – is in this case 11011111. However, the SERLCD want's you to send hexadecimal to it.

11011111 in hexadecimal is "DF".
The code to send this hexadecimal instruction would be the following, based on your example code:

```py
i2c.writeto(114, '\xDF')
```